# Form submission issue: data not inserting into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm encountering an issue with my web form where the submitted data is not getting inserted into the database. I've manually added data to the database, but when I submit the form, nothing happens.

I have three files: index.php, script.js, and submit.php.

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue and identifying where the problem might be coming from?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Student Registration Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Student Registration Form</h2>
        
        <!-- Display Error Message -->
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            echo "<p class='error'>{$_GET['error']}</p>";
        }
        ?>

        <form id="registrationForm" method="post" action="./submit.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]{11}" required>
                <small>Format: 11 digits without spaces or dashes</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="student_password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.getElementById("registrationForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting

    // Get form values
    let firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    let lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    let phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    // Do something with the form values (e.g., send them to a server)
    console.log("First Name:", firstName);
    console.log("Last Name:", lastName);
    console.log("Phone Number:", phoneNumber);
    console.log("Password:", password);

    // Clear the form
    document.getElementById("registrationForm").reset();
});
```

```
<?php
// Database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$db_password = ""; 
$dbname = "student_registration_portal";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Form data
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$userPassword = $_POST['student_password']; 

// Insert data into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, phone_number, student_password)
        VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$phoneNumber', '$userPassword')";

// Execute SQL query
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    // Log error
    error_log("Error: " . $sql . "\n" . $conn->error);
    
    // Output error message
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// Close database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

[the xampp mysql database and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDo31.png)

I'm encountering an issue with my web form where the submitted data is not getting inserted into the database. I've manually added data to the database, but when I submit the form, nothing happens.

I have three files: index.php, script.js, and submit.php.

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue and identifying where the problem might be coming from?

Added logs to check errors and its clean. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tt8V.png)

I have added logs in script.js and error catching in submit.php but they are clean. I am using php 8.2.16 version and vs code

Comment: Does the server receive the request? chances are, it won't since you `// Prevent the form from submitting` - in your troubleshooting, did you check to see if any request was made from the client to the server?

Comment: Never store plain text passwords. PHP has [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: _"I'm encountering an issue with my web form where the submitted data is not getting inserted into the database."_ - what submitted data ...? You prevented the _default_ action of the form submission, and between logging some values to the console and then _resetting_ the form, you are not doing anything to facilitate the sending of the data to the server yourself ... `// Do something with the form values (e.g., send them to a server)` - you did not do the suggested "e.g.", you only logged a bit of stuff to the console.

Comment: Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a `'` in their name (such as `O'Reilly`)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `O`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk (because plain-text passwords can be stolen by hackers). Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Hashed passwords cannot be decoded by anyone who steals them.

Comment: And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  @JaromandaX  I haven't checked whether the server receives the request. Could you please advise me on how to do that? I'm relatively new to web development and would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Your browser contains Developer Tools (press F12 in most browsers), which has (among many other useful tools which are essential for any web developer to know how to use) a Network tool which can show  you all the traffic going between your web page and any webservers it interacts with. Load your page, open the tool, make sure the "preserve log" box is ticked and then submit your form. If that doesn't cause an entry to be added to the log pointing to "submit.php" then you'll know it didn't send the data to the server.

Answer (score -2):

Please check your credentials such as $servername,$db_username,$db_password and check field names such as firstName, lastName, phoneNumber & password & check config file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).